# Преобразование типа 'str' в 'dict' используя ast.literal_eval

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Использую Python2.7. Нужно преобразовать str->dict и с этом неплохо справляется команда ast.literal_eval, правда только в терминале:

```
$python
>>>import ast
>>>s = '{...}' #str type
>>>d = ast.literal_eval(s) #dict type
```

Когда добавляю этот скрипт в программу - происходит магия и он перестает работать. Выглядит это так:

```
result = re.recognize_by_file(inputFile, X)
result_dict = ast.literal_eval(result)
```

Вот когда добавляешь этот код - вылетает ошибка:

```
File "<string>", line 0
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Прочел что проблема может быть в версии Python, но возможности сменить его нет.
Вывод типов и пример самой строки result:

```
print(result)
```

> {"status":{"msg":"No result","code":1001,"version":"1.0"}}

```
print(type(result))
```

> type 'str'

```
result_dict = ast.literal_eval(result) #Ну дальше типы я не могу выводить, потому что вылетает ошибка.
```

---

Полный вывод выглядит так:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/maxlager/PyCharm_Projects/BOT_2.7/bot.py", line 42, in  <module>
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
File "/home/maxlager/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 183, in polling
self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
File "/home/maxlager/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 207, in __threaded_polling
self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
File "/home/maxlager/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 103, in raise_exceptions
six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
File "/home/maxlager/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 54, in run
task(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/maxlager/PyCharm_Projects/BOT_2.7/bot.py", line 38, in handler_text
result_dict = ast.literal_eval(result)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
File "<unknown>", line 0

^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

42 строка выглядит так:

```
 bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Здесь нужно юзать json.loads

Answer (score 5):

В Питоне отступы в исходном коде имеют значение:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('""\n')
''
>>> ast.literal_eval('""\n ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 2

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

На последней строчке присутствует неожиданный отступ. Ошибка является артефактом реализации `ast.literal_eval()` (возможный баг так как для распознавания констант пробелы в конце не должны иметь значения—результат одно значение, а не набор инструкций). Обойти это поведение можно с помощью `.rstrip()`.

В вашем случае, лучше `json.loads()` использовать [как @andreymal порекомендовал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527894/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-str-%d0%b2-dict-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-ast-literal-eval#comment656381_527894).